# meaning of "scrambled infant"

Tags: translation

Can you plase help me to understand phrase "scrambled infant"? I can understand each word separately but not together at least clearly. This phrase is bolded below in subtitles of The Angry Birds movie.

> ...
>   113 00:07:06,680 --> 00:07:12,232 Your Honor, our family has always
>   practiced natural childhatch.
>
> 114 00:07:12,320 --> 00:07:16,199 The risks of having **a scrambled
>   infant** are too great.
>
> 115 00:07:16,280 --> 00:07:17,952 There was going to be music,
>
> 116 00:07:18,080 --> 00:07:21,231 the nest was going to be full of
>   beautiful, fresh-cut flowers.
>   ...

Comment: It's a joke. Birds lay eggs. Eggs get scrambled.

Comment: You understood "natural childhatch" though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reference to the way humans are born -- child*birth*, as opposed to child*hatch*, which is of course for the birds. Some people think that children should be born with no medical interference, and that instead of doctors and drugs, the mother might be better accompanied during labor by music and flowers during labor. This is called *natural childbirth*. Of course, human evolution has made childbirth a somewhat difficult an dangerous procedure, in which things can go terribly wrong. This is not at all parallel to birds laying eggs, but that supposed parallel is the conceit here.  What's a "bad" outcome for an egg? To be scrambled -- all mixed up in the wrong order --and that's applied to the chick, I mean "infant".

Comment: Thank you very much you found time to answer me in so details. I am very happy. :-)

Comment: It's important to realize that the respondent apparently thinks of him/herself as having the nature of a bird. I'm not sure if this is a quote from an actual court case or if it's a movie or TV show featuring a sympathetic crazy. The subject matter (death of an infant) seems too dark for an animated movie featuring anthropomorphized animals.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Actual court case? Dude, it's from the *Angry Birds* movie.

Comment: @deadrat - Well, there goes my cartoon credibility.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Not to worry. Perhaps it diminishes your credibility on the topic, but It can only redound to your credit overall.